# How to scale a CSG object in JCSG

Tags: java

This may be basic, but is there a function for scaling CSG objects? I would like to use the bounds and a scale function to automatically generate keepaway zones for 3d printed parts with a known overlap tolerance (usually nozzle diameter). I can get the bounds form the CSG object but can not seem to find a scale function.

Answer (score 1):

In JCSG all `CSG` objects have a [CSG#transformed(Transform t)](https://github.com/miho/JCSG/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/mihosoft/vrl/v3d/CSG.java#L930) method that can contain arbitrary transforms. To scale an object the [Transform#scale(double x, double y, double z)](https://github.com/miho/JCSG/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/mihosoft/vrl/v3d/Transform.java#L312) can be used.

**Example:**

```
CSG csg       = // your csg object that shall be scaled
CSG scaledCSG = csg.transormed(Transform.unity().scale(2.0,2.0,2.0));
```